# C# regular expression trouble

Tags: c#, regex, filehelpers

## Problem!

I Have the following input (rules) from a flat file (talking about numeric input):

- Input might be a natural number (below 1000): `1, 10, 100, 999, ...`
- Input might be a comma separated number surrounded by quotes (above 1000): `"1,000", "2,000", "3,000", "10,000", ...`

I Have the following regular expression to validate the input: `(?:(\d+)|\x22([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)\x22)`, So for an input like `10` I'm expecting in the first matching group `10`, which is exactly what I got. But when I got an input like `"10,000"` I'm expecting in the first matching group `10,000`, but it is stored at the second matching group.

## Example

```
string text1 = "\"" + "10,000" + "\"";
string text2 = "50";

string pattern = @"(\d+)|\x22([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+){0,})\x22";

Match match1 = Regex.Match(text1, pattern);
Match match2 = Regex.Match(text2, pattern);

if (match1.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match#1 Group#1: " + match1.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Match#1 Group#2: " + match1.Groups[2].Value);

    # Outputs
    # Match#1 Group#1: 
    # Match#1 Group#2: 10,000
}

if (match2.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Match#2 Group#1: " + match2.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Match#2 Group#2: " + match2.Groups[2].Value);

    # Outputs
    # Match#2 Group#1: 50
    # Match#2 Group#2: 
}
```

## Expected Result

Both results on the same matching group, in this case `1`

## Questions?

- What am I doing wrong? I'm just getting bad grouping from the regular expression matches.
- Also, I'm using [filehelpers .NET](http://www.filehelpers.com/) to parse the file, is there any other way to resolve this problem. Actualy I'm trying to implement a custom converter.

**Object File**

```
[FieldConverter(typeof(OOR_Quantity))]
public Int32 Quantity;
```

**OOR_Quantity**

```
internal class OOR_Quantity : ConverterBase
{
    public override object StringToField(string from)
    {
        string pattern = @"(?:(\d+)|\x22([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)\x22)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        if (regex.IsMatch(from))
        {
            Match match = regex.Match(from);
            return int.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
        }

        throw new ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Group numbers are assigned purely on the basis of their positions in the regex--specifically, the relative position of the opening bracket, `(`.  In your regex, `(\d+)` is the first group and `([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)` is the second.

If you want to refer to them both with the same identifier, use named groups and give them both the same name:

```
@"(?:(?<NUMBER>\d+)|\x22(?<NUMBER>[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*)\x22)"
```

Now you can retrieve the captured value as `match.Groups["NUMBER"].Value`.

Comment: I don't know if I really forgot about this, or if I completely misunderstood the rule. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested the regex below with Ruby:

```
text1 = "\"10,000\""
text2 = "50"

regex = /"?([0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+){0,})"?/

text1 =~ regex
puts "#$1"

text2 =~ regex
puts "#$1"
```

The result is:

```
10,000
50
```

I think you can rewrite in C#. Isn't it enough for you?

Comment: Nice and simple answer, but you are not forcing the double quotes to appear or not.